# How to change the collection name on an index

Tags: ravendb

When I save a document that has a generic type `DataView<Customer>`, I'm manually setting the collection name to "customers". However, I'm having some trouble making an index using `AbstractIndexCreationTask` with a non-default collection name. Here's my index:

```
public class customers_Search
    : AbstractIndexCreationTask<DataView<Customer>, customers_Search.Result>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Query { get; set; }
    }

    public customers_Search()
    {
        Map = customers =>
            from customer in customers
            where customer.Data != null
            select new
            {
                Query = AsDocument(customer.Data).Select(x => x.Value)
            };
        Index(x => x.Query, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```

When this gets deployed, it looks like this:

```
from customer in docs.DataViewOfCustomer
where customer.Data != null
select new {
    Query = customer.Data.Select(x => x.Value)
}
```

This doesn't work obviously, and if I change DataViewOfCustomer to "customers" it works just fine.

I'd rather not have to use non-type-checked (string) indexes to deploy. **Is there a way to set the collection name that from the `AbstractIndexCreationTask` class?**

---

**Update**

Since my data class is generic, I made a generic index which fixes up the names.

```
public class DataViewQuery<TEntity>
    : AbstractIndexCreationTask<DataView<TEntity>, DataViewQueryResult>
{
    private readonly string _entityName;
    private readonly string _indexName;

    // this is to fix the collection name for the index name
    public override string IndexName { get { return _indexName; } }
    // this is to fix the collection name for the index query
    public override void Execute(IDatabaseCommands databaseCommands, DocumentConvention documentConvention)
    {
        var conventions = documentConvention.Clone();
        conventions.FindTypeTagName =
            type =>
                typeof(DataView<TEntity>) == type
                    ? _entityName
                    : documentConvention.FindTypeTagName(type);
        base.Execute(databaseCommands, conventions);
    }

    public DataViewQuery(string entityName)
    {
        _entityName = entityName;
        _indexName = String.Format("{0}/{1}", entityName, "Query");

        Map = items =>
            from item in items
            where item.Data != null
            select new
            {
                Query = AsDocument(item.Data).Select(x => x.Value)
            };
        Index(x => x.Query, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}

public class DataViewQueryResult
{
    public string Query { get; set; }
}
```

Then I can create a specific index which has all the configuration in it.

```
// sets the collection type (DataView<Customer>) for the index
public class CustomerQuery : DataViewQuery<Customer>
{
    // sets the collection name for the index
    public CustomerQuery() : base(EntityName.Customers) {  }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to persist the whole DataView<>? Why not just persist the Customer into Raven without the DataView?

Comment: Yes, the DataView has information that is used the UI.

Comment: After all, I've decided that it would be easier to make a view that matches conventions (e.g. named Customer), even if it just inherits from DataView<Customer> (different Customer). I don't really like the how and where of the added configuration when deviating from conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure this in the conventions.
The property to configure is FindTypeTagName

Comment: Terse answer, but I found the link on your website, [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/indexes/indexing-polymorphic-data), under Other Ways heading. In order to avoid spreading out the configuration, I overrode the index's `Execute` method, and changed the conventions there. It works.